# string property not worked properly in kivy python

Tags: python, kivy-language, kivymd

I am new to python, and my `StringProperty` doesn't work as intended.

It should show an immediate value of `CheckBox`, but it shows the value of previous click.

.py file

```py
  cuisine = StringProperty("")

    def checkbox_click(self,instance,value):
        if value is True:
            print(format(self.cuisine)) #store in database
        else:
            print("Not Checked")
```

.kv file

```
                    MDLabel: #3
                        text: "Chinese"
                        pos_hint : {"center_x":.5,"center_y":.700}
                        font_size: "11"

                    CheckBox:
                        text: "Chinese"
                        pos_hint : {"center_x":.5,"center_y":.700}
                        on_active:root.checkbox_click(self, self.active)
                        on_active:
                            root.cuisine = self.text

                    MDLabel: #4
                        text: "Indian"
                        pos_hint : {"center_x":.5,"center_y":.700}
                        font_size: "11"

                    CheckBox:
                        text: "Indian"
                        pos_hint : {"center_x":.5,"center_y":.700}
                        on_active:root.checkbox_click(self, self.active)
                        on_active:
                            root.cuisine = self.text
```

output:

```
Malay
Not Checked
Malay
Chinese
```

When `Malay` is clicked it doesn't not show up,
then when I clicked `Chinese` then `Malay` shows up,
clicked `Indian` then `Chinese` is printed.

Help me.

Comment: Try using `on_active` method once.

Comment: Would you give some example? I had tried a few but it does not work